# Creating A Bar Graph But Not Getting Value From CSV File Getting Error NaN

Tags: csv, d3.js

## Create A Bar Graph Using D3 And Getting Value from csv file From Same Folder

[image]

## But Getting Error On Console Like 15NaN

[image]

## Below Is My Code

```js
/*
define margin followed by height & width for svg
*/
//define margin
var margin = {
    top:20,right:10,bottom:100,left:40
}
//define w & h
var w = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
/*
define svg by selecting the body and append the svg to body with proper 
height and width then appen it to g
*/
var svg = d3.select("body").
    append("svg").
    attr({
        "width": w + margin.left + margin.right,
        "height": h + margin.top + margin.bottom
    }).
    append("g").
    attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");
/*
define scale then followed by axis
*/
//define x & y scale
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().
    rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.2, 0.2);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().
    range([h, 0]);
//define x& y axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().
    scale(xScale).
    orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().
    scale(yScale).
    orient("left");
/*
import the data here we have csv data
*/
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error,data) {
    if(error) console.log("Error: data not loaded!");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.country = d.country;
        d.gdp = +d.gdp;       
        console.log(d.gdp);  
    });

});
```

```css
svg {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3 Tutorial Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h1>Bar Graph - 2015 GDP Based On PPP Valuation</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## And Here Is My data.csv values

```html
country gdp
Brazil 3.20
Italy 2.17
India 8.02
Saudi Arebia 1.13
Russa 3.47
Italy 2.17
Australia 1.13
Spain 1.68
Korea 1.84
United States 17.9
China 19.51
Japan 4.84
Germany 3.84
Turkey 1.57
United Kingdom 2.66
```

## Not Sure What Is Wrong Thanks for Helping

Comment: I don't know much about D3, but the file you have posted isn't a CSV. Do you need to use the `tsv` function to read your data?

Comment: yes i can was just learning how to use

Comment: got it syntex of file should be like sn,class 1,XI

Comment: As Chris pointed out, this is not a CSV, but a TSV. Simply change the file name to "data.tsv", and in your code, change `d3.csv("data.csv", function(error,data)` to `d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error,data)`